# how to change session id after logout in php?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $b = session_id();
    if(empty($b)) session_start(); 
    $ses= session_id();
    echo $ses;
?>
```

This code is for generating the session id

But when to destroy the session the session id shown is same as the old one.When I delete the cookie then it has changed..how to change the session id?

Comment: It would probably have been faster to put that into google: `session_regenerate_id`

Comment: use `session_unset()` to destroy previous session id

Answer (score 3):

Changing the `session_id()` can be done by `session_regenerate_id()`

```
<?php
session_start();

$old_sessionid = session_id();

session_regenerate_id();

$new_sessionid = session_id();

echo "Old Session: $old_sessionid<br />";
echo "New Session: $new_sessionid<br />";

print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

To delete the session use   `session_destroy();`

```
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array(); // Clears the $_SESSION variable
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: I can destroy the session but after destroy it cannot be changed that is the problem

Comment: That is not correct, if you check the manual on `session_destroy()`: `In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset.`

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest

```
// deletes old session
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

[Link to PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)